# Symfony Seesion Time

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication

I have project Symfony 2.6.11 and after authentication some time I have [error](http://s7.uploads.ru/JMGqi.jpg) after I must authentication again and I want some information like 'You session end, authentication again' or where I see actual time for authentication and how change this time ?

Comment: Do you have a problem with spcae disk ? Because you can have a fail to write session on your server.

Comment: you see this in screen-shot ??

Comment: No but it's a symptom.

Comment: I thought maybe it's due to the time settings authentication, 
It seems to me that there is enough space, space in server ?

Comment: Please copy-paste the error code, I don't see anything on your screenshot (the stack trace only start at 9 on your screenshot).

Comment: What's the engine used ? FPM ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the session settings? :

```
framework:
    session:
            cookie_lifetime: 60 #60 seconds
            gc_maxlifetime: 50 #50 seconds - only needed for testing. Dont use this in a production environment
            gc_probability: 1 #only needed for testing. Dont use this in a production environment
            gc_divisor: 1 #only needed for testing. Dont use this in a production environment
```

You can see the config over here: https://codedump.io/share/9eVPS5otSIuk

Comment: When developer, maybe ROLE_ADMIN, authentication his data, example his slug, set in session and this is session have correct time 60 second ? I have this error after hour maybe half hour. Now in my app/config/config.yml
 session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~